# Rails 2.1.0 Server log problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Guys, I have to work with some legacy `Rails 2.1.0` app for some reasons. They have designed it to use Ruby 1.8.6.

I installed RVM and installed `ruby 1.8.7`. I installed all of the gems that the app requires (a real pain in Rails 2.x app compared to Bundler) and started the rails app using script/server command.

The problem arises with the server log I am getting. In `development` rails mode, the log always comes in "info" mode and not in "debug" mode. In debug mode, our server log will show request params, controller & action, response time and everything. But all I get is this kind of log.

```
Referer -> /images/events-dir.png?1297230128
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2011:06:50:36 IST] "GET /images/org-url.png?1297230128 HTTP/1.1" 200 141824
Referer -> /images/org-url.png?1297230128
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2011:06:50:36 IST] "GET /images/iphone-frame.png HTTP/1.1" 200 47899
Referer -> /images/iphone-frame.png
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2011:06:50:36 IST] "GET /images/ipad-frame.png HTTP/1.1" 200 273013
Referer -> /images/ipad-frame.png
```

Damn, its really hard to work with this kind of log. I have explicitly mentioned

config.log_level = :debug

in environment.rb. But still after this, the output comes in "info" mode. Am i using the wrong ruby version. should I specifically use ruby 1.8.6 to get the desired/expected log output. Please help, I'm stuck in this for "days".

The important thing is when I `tail -f` my development.log file, that file shows the correct format. essentially, when I start my server, it should start in "development" mode and it should `tail -f` the development log. right ?

Answer (score 0):

The log levels come in : `:debug, :info, :warn, :error, and :fatal`

Fatal being the least and debug being the most output. I think you want the least, so choose fatal of level 4.

```
Rails.logger.level = 4
```

Also you mentioned that the Ruby you're using is 1.8.6, but you installed 1.8.7. I would imagine you need to `rvm install ruby-1.8.6` to get this working properly.